# Loading several files depending on file name (with AWS Glue)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a bucket in s3 and I would like to load only the files with names fileName then a number. Is there anything like the below that works? The below doesn't work (without the [0-9] it works).

```
df = glueContext.read.load(
    "s3://bucketName/fileName[0-9]*.csv",
    format="csv",
    sep=",",
    header="true"
    )
```

Comment: Are you really using AWS glue context? Can you add the related code in question too?

Comment: yes, I am. It's some joins, some renameing some other stuff like this, nothing complicated. is glue context not good?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that if your code works. The only issue I see here is, you are using bash style file expansion `[0-9]` in Python code. If this function supports loading multiple csv files, you can generate another list of s3 paths based on regexp and pass that list to load() function.

Comment: The code above doen't work. this would work `"s3://bucketName/fileName*.csv"` but not with `[0-9]`

Comment: Try with python glob module, https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/glob.html